# Page/Form goes back to itself upon submitting instead of going to the specified page

Tags: php

We just started PHP  in my webscripting class today, and I'm already having problems with my first PHP assignment. Its more of me not understanding what is going on or overlooking something I don't fully know yet.

The code here: http://codepad.org/KnHda3iS is supposed to go to php4_1input.php but upon submitting it goes to back to itself (this page is called php4_1storyselphp). I'm not exactly sure why it does this but I presume I overlooked something really silly or just haven't learned why this is happening yet.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `print`? use `echo`.

Comment: @Jacob: How does that affect the form submission?

Comment: Also, try closing your html tags, I see some tags that are malformed.

Comment: Ill go ahead and try that but I presume that isn't the problem? Id be getting an error and/or my malformed HTML tags would actually print instead of "working," correct?

Comment: I don't know if there are unclosed tags in your code. But always run through validations to check your markup, because not all unclosed tags will scramble the page. And, malformed HTML will never display an error message on your page. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a form tag opened under the body tag. Remove it. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have two `form` elements on the page. This will work: http://codepad.org/3laSb9c2

Answer (score 0):

You have a hanging form tag & also the action on the form should just be /cgi-bin/assignment4/php4_1input.php

Comment: Absolute URL in action is not a problem for GET submissions.